# Cors not physically saving cookie

Tags: apache, http, https, cors

After hours of digging and testing i got my local frontent (angular2) to speak with a dev backend.
Using `withCredentials: true` on https request and htaccess:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://127.0.0.1:3000"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST"
```

It's all fine until i reload the page - and i have to login again.
This is sent with requests, but cookie PHPSESSID is not actually saved on disk:

```
Cookie:PHPSESSID=jp65lr9tviq6n5q9s1i0fupuq7
```

If i build the code and upload to the same server where backend is, not using CORS  - it all works fine, but i cannot do that when i develop frontend locally.

Response Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://127.0.0.1:3000
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:105
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 04 Apr 2017 14:15:56 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-GB,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:62
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:PHPSESSID=cjoe07094u4139i7c0pb4cd3e7
Host:dev.server.com
Origin:https://127.0.0.1:3000
Referer:https://127.0.0.1:3000/login
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

What am i missing here?

UPDATE:
It seems like it does save it - under wrong domain. The cookie is set under the api server domain and localhost cannot find it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a proxy in webpack settings:

```
  proxy: {
    '/authenticate': {
      target: 'https://dev.server.com',
      secure: false,
      changeOrigin: true
    },
    '/Api': {
      target: 'https://dev.server.com',
      secure: false,
      changeOrigin: true
    }
  }
```

Together with withCredentials: true got around the issue.